# Amazon SNS bounce event is not fired

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have an issue with Amazon SES and Amazon SNS.
following this doc : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html#SendMessageToHttp.confirm

Amazon SES gives you the opportunity to call an URL when some events are fired (like bounces and deliveries).
In order to configure it, we need three things :

- a valid email address
  [image]
- a valid Topic in Amazon SNS (Push Notification Service)
  [image]
- a valid subscription to a topic
  [image]

The objective is to call the end point when sending an email to an not existant address. so I configured my email notifications like that. 
[image]
I just linked my topic to my address. But the bounce event is never fired.
(I sent an email to fzada@azef.fr (which is of course an non existent email))

I've also tried to link the topic to the delivery event, and it works like a charm (this time I send an email to my personal address), I don't understand the difference between these two events. But in delivery case all is functional.

I configure my endpoint to http://admin.nlv3.fr/nlv3/bounce.
In the delivery event case my URL is correctly called. 
In the bounce event case this same url is never called

Do I need to configure something else in order to have bounce event ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted some real world data on this as an answer to a similar question recently.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29977793/4179009

Amazon will keep trying to deliver to bad domains for hours.  I typically receive bad domain bounces 12-16 hours after the mail was sent.  I presume this is to account for times when DNS could be temporarily down or incorrect or if a mail server is offline temporarily.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the problem was here. I have received severals test mails 12h later...

Answer (score 1):

A bounce to a "fake" email address, particularly to an apparently fake (non-existent) domain like this, could take several hours to return, since the system should be expected to retry a number of times before giving up.  You should *eventually* see these come in, but there's a better way:

Test against the [simulator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mailbox-simulator.html), by sending a message to bounce@simulator.amazonses.com, which will cause a "hard" bounce (while what you're trying is more likely to cause a "soft" bounce, at least for a few hours), and fire the notification almost immediately (without being counted against you).

See also: [the various outcomes that can occur after the email is sent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-email-with-ses.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help, the test with amazon bounce email helps me, i have read the documentation for that but i was thinking about the fact that amazon will have the same behaviour with a fake email

Comment: "fire the notification almost immediately" - I wish that were still true.

Comment: @john it's been a while since I used the simulator.  Is it not as quick as it used to be?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Sadly not. During testing today, I received no notifications whatsoever for bounces / complaints using the simulator. I didn't even receive any e-mails (I added an e-mail subscription in case my notification service was breaking). It's a shame.